# Continuous deployment of a react app on netlify rendering blank page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, netlify

I just finished a continuous deployment from Github on netlify. With these setting:

```
Build Command: npm build
Publish Directory: devit/public/
```

It deployed without any errors, on visiting the site it was blank.
Complete Deploy log :

```
4:10:30 AM: Build ready to start
4:10:32 AM: build-image version: ca811f47d4c1cbd1812d1eb6ecb0c977e86d1a1d
4:10:32 AM: build-image tag: v3.3.20
4:10:32 AM: buildbot version: 78b5536ab4f742c26705d3e953381b9cde6e22ef
4:10:32 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
4:10:32 AM: Starting to download cache of 88.5MB
4:10:33 AM: Finished downloading cache in 724.248229ms
4:10:33 AM: Starting to extract cache
4:10:35 AM: Finished extracting cache in 2.554192297s
4:10:35 AM: Finished fetching cache in 3.297079366s
4:10:35 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
4:10:36 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
4:10:37 AM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'devit/public' versus 'devit/public/' in the Netlify UI
4:10:37 AM: Starting build script
4:10:37 AM: Installing dependencies
4:10:37 AM: Python version set to 2.7
4:10:38 AM: Started restoring cached node version
4:10:40 AM: Finished restoring cached node version
4:10:41 AM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
4:10:41 AM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
4:10:41 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
4:10:41 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
4:10:41 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
4:10:42 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
4:10:43 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
4:10:43 AM: 5.2 is already installed.
4:10:43 AM: Using Swift version 5.2
4:10:43 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
4:10:43 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
4:10:43 AM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
4:10:43 AM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
4:10:43 AM: Installing missing commands
4:10:43 AM: Verify run directory
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
4:10:44 AM: │        Netlify Build        │
4:10:44 AM: └─────────────────────────────┘
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ❯ Version
4:10:44 AM:   @netlify/build 2.0.27
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ❯ Flags
4:10:44 AM:   deployId: 5f0547367d92cb55b46de080
4:10:44 AM:   mode: buildbot
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ❯ Current directory
4:10:44 AM:   /opt/build/repo
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ❯ Config file
4:10:44 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ❯ Context
4:10:44 AM:   production
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
4:10:44 AM: │ 1. Build command from Netlify app │
4:10:44 AM: └───────────────────────────────────┘
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: $ npm build
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: (build.command completed in 274ms)
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
4:10:44 AM: │   Netlify Build Complete    │
4:10:44 AM: └─────────────────────────────┘
4:10:44 AM: ​
4:10:44 AM: (Netlify Build completed in 298ms)
4:10:44 AM: Caching artifacts
4:10:44 AM: Started saving build plugins
4:10:44 AM: Finished saving build plugins
4:10:44 AM: Started saving pip cache
4:10:44 AM: Finished saving pip cache
4:10:44 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Started saving go dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
4:10:44 AM: Build script success
4:10:44 AM: Starting to deploy site from 'devit/public'
4:10:44 AM: Creating deploy tree 
4:10:45 AM: Creating deploy upload records
4:10:45 AM: 0 new files to upload
4:10:45 AM: 0 new functions to upload
4:10:45 AM: Starting post processing
4:10:45 AM: Post processing - HTML
4:10:46 AM: Post processing - redirect rules
4:10:46 AM: Post processing - header rules
4:10:46 AM: Post processing done
4:10:46 AM: Site is live
4:10:56 AM: Finished processing build request in 24.126985051s
```

I also checked the browser console, and found this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nqt1.png

GitHub repository : https://github.com/kelvinyelyen/dev.it_blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm build` does not run your `build` script, it builds an npm package, which doesn't do anything useful for a website. You'd also have to use the `devit` directory.

Setting the build command to `npm run build --prefix devit` should fix the issue.

Comment: Now detects package.json and the build script but logs an error. This is the build script: " node public/server.js && react-script build"

Comment: You can't run a Node server in Netlify, and this will also never run the build script anyway. You should remove your Node server, port it to Netlify functions, or use another host like Heroku or AWS for your backend.